# Unable to import old database after reinstall (permission issue with information_schema)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1044

I have recently re-installed my dev. computer.

So what I did was make an export in phpmyadmin into an .sql file and backedup all the site files.
Something that normally should be enough?

Now my problem is that It will only partially import untill it runs into the information_schema database...

For some reason I can't get acces to it...

Is there a way I can get this import to work again?

The error I get:

```
CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

I hope one of you guys can help me.

Grtz, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `information_schema` is a MySQL system DB, I guess that MySQL will only allow you to modify its contents, not its structure.

Then you should only try to import data into it, not issue a `CREATE DATABASE information_schema` command.

BTW, is this DB `information_schema` already existing on your system ?

Comment: Yes it allready exists, I'll try changing the way it's importing the backup, THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Please open this link then you can get a solution:

1. Click on  MySQL® Database Wizard
2. Create new DATABASE
3. Create NEW USER AND PASSWORD
4. Give ALL PRIVILEGES to current user
5. Success END.

NOW CLICK ON phpMyAdmin then find your DATABASE.

Refer:[how-to-quick-install-and-start-your-website-right-away-with-wordpress](http://www.flamescorpion.com/how-to-quick-install-and-start-your-website-right-away-with-wordpress/)